# The use of English language in mathematics

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, terminology, article-writing

My question is about the use of English language in mathematics.

Should I write
"Given a basis $b_n$ of the linear space $B_n := span\,b_n$..."
or "Given a basis $b_n$ of a linear space $B_n := span\,b_n$...",
i.e., should I use "a" or "the" when referring to $B_n$? 
Here $b_n$ denotes any basis and we define $B_n$ so it is mentioned for the first time.

Comment: I would prefer "the."  And would usually prefer "vector space."

Comment: You are given a basis of a linear space that is defined by the basis. Hmm... How about, "Given a linearly independent set of vectors $b_n$ with linear span $B_n$ ..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the word "the" here; you are referencing the unique space that is the span of your basis.

Comment: I have another similar question. There are two sentences. The first one is "Given a basis $b = \{ b_0,b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$ of the linear space $B := span\,b$...". In the second one, should I write "the basis $c  := b \setminus \{b_0\}$ of the space $C := span\,c$"? Should I use "the" when referring to $c$?

Comment: My feeling is yes; the basis $b\setminus \{b_0\}$ is unique.